# Como importar meu icone para minha página

Tags: html, css, svg, font, icons

Olá,
Eu quero utilizar meu próprios icones em meus projetos, porém não sei como adicioná-los e não encontrei a solução pela Web.
Até agora, eu fiz todos os ícones em SVG (para isso utilizei o Inkscape).
Observando fontes disponíveis no mercado, como Font Awesome ou o Google Fonts, percebi que tem uma forma de fazer pelo CSS.
Coloquei todos os meus icones em uma pasta no projeto e criei um arquivo CSS, resumidamente assim:

```css
.mf {
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  line-height: 1; 
}

.mf-user:before { content: "\i100"; }

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Minhas Fontes';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-display: auto;
  src: url("../icons/fonts/svgs/regular/fonts.svg") format("svg"); 
  }
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/icons/fonts/css/fonts.css">
    <title>Minhas Fontes</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button><i class="mf mf-user"></i></button>
  <button><i class="fa fa-user"></i></button>
</body>
```

No exemplo acima, eu coloquei o meu ícone e o do Font Awesome, cada um em um botão, entretanto o do Font Awesome aparece, já no meu aparece escrito "i100".
Meu projeto está assim:

```html
.
├── index.html
└── resources
    └── icons
        └── fonts
            ├── css
            │   └── fonts.css
            └── svgs
                └── regular
                    └── user.svg
```

O que mais falta para eu fazer? Como eu vinculo o "\i100" ao ícone user.svg?
Obrigado, galera!

Comment: De cara, faltou aplicar o `font-family: 'Minhas Fontes';` na sua classe `.mf`. Já a parte de vincular o `"\i100"` a algum ícone, acredito ser no programa onde você criou a "fonte", seguindo o princípio de que cada ícone é um caractere da fonte representados por cada código.

Comment: Pode dar uma olhada nesse [tutorial para criar fontes](https://velhobit.com.br/design/como-criar-sua-propria-fonte-e-a-usar-como-icone.html). Não vou formular resposta sobre, já que acaba não sendo sobre programação. Apenas uma dica.

Comment: Não é assim que funciona, não dá para usar um SVG como se fosse uma fonte. Essa sintaxe que você usou é pra outra coisa (SVG fonts, que não funcionam em diversos browsers, e, quando funcionam, funcionam mal). Para fazer como o fontawesome, crie uma fonte de verdade, usando ferramentas especializadas para isso.